# Programmatically close Data Viewer tabs in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I wanted to make a script that closes all Data Viewer tabs in RStudio (those invoked by clicking on a data object in the Environment pane, or by calling `utils::View()`) but keeps all the "usual" document tabs.
First, I found `rstudioapi::documentClose()` function - not sure if it works for Data Viewer tabs, it requires the document id that seems to be not applicable here: calling `getActiveDocumentContext()` on Data Viewer tab returns `#console`.
Then, there's `executeCommand('closeSourceDoc')` option that closes the current tab, whether it is Data Viewer or standard document. I could probably use `executeCommand('nextTab')` to loop through all opened tabs, but I can't find how to determine if the active tab is Data Viewer or not...
Any hints?

Comment: It is an [open issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/9761)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code seems to do what you want.

```
Tabs=c()
doc=rstudioapi::documentPath()
while (is.null(doc)||!doc%in% Tabs) {  
   if(is.null(doc)){    
     rstudioapi::executeCommand('closeSourceDoc')  
   }     
   rstudioapi::executeCommand('nextTab')
   Tabs=c(Tabs,doc);  
   doc=rstudioapi::documentPath()
}
```

Comment: cool! it almost does it, except that it also tries to close unsaved new docs (those "Untitled1" etc)